# Signal/image processing using python?Additional IDE must required or default pyhton IDLE is sufficent?

Tags: image-processing, python

Can we perform signal processing and image processing using default pyhton IDLE(that is downloaded from pyhton website) for scenarios where we may also need plotting etc? or is it necesssary to install some other advanced IDE like anaconda or pycharm etc?

Comment: This might be better suited to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)

Comment: Plain Python works, yes. But it's a massive waste of time, and much harder. I recommend [Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder) & Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

Jupyter Notebooks which isn't an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) is my peferred solution for doing interactive work with signal processing and plotting . You can mix rich graphics and formatted text with interactive code and plots for demonstrating and documenting your work. See example graphic below:

[image: Example Jupyter Notebook]

JupyterLab is starting to incorporate many IDE features to be useful as a full-fledged IDE, but as of now they are not up to the level that I would need in an IDE.

Spyder and other more advanced IDE's are more suitable for detailed code development (PyCharm, VIsualStudio, and Eclipse all support Python well- the latter are good if you are already using them for other languages) given development features such as single step debugging.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode is your best bet for python DSP development. It offers a rich set of tools, and works well with a variety of other languages, and version control (i.e., git).